# The selected configuration for displays could not be applied

Tags: 11.10, ati, multiple-monitors

Just installed 11.10 64bit and followed [this guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Generate_a_new_.2Fetc.2FX11.2Fxorg.conf_file) to install the latest drivers for my Radeon HD 4870.

I have a 24" and a 17" side by side. The larger screen is turned on by default, but the smaller one doesn't work unless I *mirror* them. When I remove mirroring, the small screen is automatically disabled. I enable it, choose a resolution, and when I press apply I get:

```
required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(3200, 1200), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1920, 1920)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have similar setup (but with nvidia 6200), and I am getting the same.

Answer (score 30):

**First need to install the restricted drivers for access to aticonfig

I had the same problem. Run `sudo aticonfig --initial`, to re-initialize your configuration files.

Now I'm not sure if restart was necessary here or not.

Now run 'sudo amdcccle' and you'll be able to configure dual display. Go to `Display Manager` and choose `Multi-display desktop with display(s)...` in `Multi-Display` tab for both monitors.
**restart after this,
Then disable the "mirror monitors" option in the Ubuntu display settings.

Comment: I'll try that in a bit and let you know.

Comment: In addition, it is important that you also have go back to the "Displays" setting, and enable the dual monitor (on top of what you already did in amdcccle". It is working now on 11.10 :) Fantastic

Comment: Helped me on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with hp envy m6 :) thanks